# Counter not giving the expected result

Tags: c++

I am writing a program for a C++ class that computes Armstrong numbers. The program works fine except each output line is supposed to read as:

```
Armstrong number 1: xxx
Armstrong number 2: xxx
Armstrong number 3: xxx
Armstrong number 4: xxx, etc...
```

The computations are correct but the counter to give the incremental number "Armstrong number 1", 2, 3, etc only reflects the actual armstrong result. I need it to count the displayed lines.

The code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Change the console's background color.
    system ("color F0");

    // Declare the variables
    int i = 0, counter = 1, var1, var2, var3, var4;

    while (i < 1000)
    {
        var1 = i/100;
        var2 = (i % 100) / 10;
        var3 = (i % 100) % 10;
        var4 = (var1 * var1 * var1) + (var2 * var2 * var2) + (var3 * var3 * var3);

        if (i == var4)

            cout << "\n Armstrong number " << counter << ": " << var4;
            counter++;
            i++;


    }
        cout << "\n";
        system ("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

How do I fix this?

What I need is:
Armstrong number 1:   0
Armstrong number 2:   1
Armstrong number 3: 153
Armstrong number 4: 370

What I get is:
Armstrong number 0:   0
Armstrong number 1:   1
Armstrong number 153: 153
Armstrong number 370: 370

Comment: What value are you expecting? What value are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the indentation, it appears maybe you need brackets that you forgot:

```
   if (i == var4)
   {
        cout << "\n Armstrong number " << counter << ": " << var4;
        counter++;
   }
   i++;
```

Without the brackets, only the `cout` is "in" the `if` statement.  The increment of `counter` and `i` would execute every time.

After looking more closely, I believe that the `i++` is supposed to be outside the closing bracket.

Comment: Mark - When I added the brackets the output stopped at 2. I got the expected response for "Armstrong number 1:" and "Armstrong number 2:" but then the program just sits with ... after the second output line.

Comment: *Aside:* [Weird markdown rendering!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169410/147331)

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  What is also weird is that I did not notice it.  I copied the original block from the OP and then just deleted spaces ... or so I thought.  It "looked" normal to me after the fact.  I need to pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

Some advices on style:

if you need initialize/check/increase loop use for(), it is designed for that
This is C++, not C, declare your variables right before you use them
Increment operator specially designed to use inside statements, so if you use variable only  once and right after that increment it, you go against that design

```
int counter = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    int var1 = i/100;
    int var2 = (i % 100) / 10;
    int var3 = (i % 100) % 10;
    int var4 = (var1 * var1 * var1) + (var2 * var2 * var2) + (var3 * var3 * var3);

    if (i == var4)
         cout << "\n Armstrong number " << counter++ << ": " << var4;
}
```

Your code not only become more readable and easier to understand, but you will eliminate many errors, including one you have in your code already.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Wilkins has nailed your key bug, but I'd also note you're not checking for Armstrong numbers correctly. It should only be cubed for 3 digit numbers. For two digit it should be squared and I'm not sure the concept makes sense for single digit numbers.

Also, why are you starting your counter at one?

Comment: I changed it back to zero, I was experimenting to see if the counter issue was a result of starting at zero.